# MySQL regarding Sort Size and efficiency

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, optimization

So I am trying to figure out a little bit of optimization with regards to MySQL and the sort rows functionality. As I understand it you can set a max row comparison and it is a good idea to set this fairly high if your machines memory can take it to reduce I/O. My question is does the memory get allocated dynamically as you load in more things to sort or statically as a massive block? Basically if I know 100% for sure I will never have more than say 1000 rows to sort would it be more efficient to set a max rows of say 1200,to give a small buffer just in case, versus 1 million. Thanks for your answers and sorry if I'm not explicit enough I'm still very new to SQL and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

When MySQL needs to sort a resultset, such as to satisfy an `SELECT ... ORDER BY`, it will act in one of several ways:

1. If the `ORDER BY` can be handled by an `INDEX`, no sort is needed.
2. If the number of rows is 'small' (and some other criteria), it will create a `MEMORY` table in RAM and use an in-memory sort to do the work.  This is very fast.  Such temp-MEMORY tables are limited by both `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size`.  Since multiple connections may be doing such simultaneously, it is a good idea to not set those higher than, say, 1% of RAM.
3. If that overflows or otherwise fails, a MyISAM table is built instead.  This can have essentially unlimited size.  Still, because of caching, it may or may not spill to disk, thereby incurring I/O.

There are other cases where MySQL will sort things.  For example, creating an index may gather all the info, sort it, then spew the info into the BTree for the index.  This probably involves an Operating System sort, which, again, may or may not involved I/O.

1200 rows is *likely* to be done in RAM; 1M rows is *likely* to involve I/O.

But, the bottom line is:  Don't worry about it.  If you need `ORDER BY`, use it.  Let MySQL do it the best way it can.